# jstree ajax call to servlet failing?

Tags: ajax, servlets, jstree

was trying to implement a simple demo of jstree using jstree json and servlet but my ajax call to servlet is not working must be a minor error but still not working please guide me 
on this would very grateful.

1) The jsp page called the jsp tree initialization on page load

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Chetan Jtree</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/themes/default/style.min.css" />
<script
    src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jstree.min.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jtreedemo.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="initTrees()">
<div id="jstreeloaddiv"></div>

</body>
```

2) The js file where the inittree function is written jtreedemo

```
function initTrees() {
  $("#jstreeloaddiv").jstree({
            "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui" ],
            "json_data" : {
                "ajax" : {
                    "type" : "POST",
                    "url" : "/JSTreeDemoServlet",
                    "data" : function(n) {
                        return {
                            "criteria" : "get_children"
                        };
                    },
                    "success" : function(new_data) {
                        alert(new_data);
                        return new_data;
                    },
                    "error" : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('request failed' + textStatus);
                    },
                    "fail" : function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

3) The servlet from where the json data is being send and to which ajax call fails.

```
@WebServlet("/JSTreeDemoServlet")
public class JSTreeDemoServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public JSTreeDemoServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("criteria"));
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray jsonarrattr = new JSONArray();
        PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();

        System.out.println(request.getParameter("criteria"));

        for(int i =0;i<5;i++){
            JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonarrattr = new JSONArray();
                jsonobj.put("data", "Bmw"+i);
                jsonarr.put(jsonobj);

                jsonobj = new JSONObject();
                jsonobj.put("id", i);
                jsonobj.put("name", "chetan");
                jsonarrattr.put(jsonobj);

                jsonobj = new JSONObject();
                jsonobj.put("attr", jsonarrattr);
                jsonarr.put(jsonobj);

                jsonobj = new JSONObject();
                jsonobj.put("state", "closed");
                jsonarr.put(jsonobj);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        out.print(jsonarr);
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "not working"? What is that you expect and what is happening?

Comment: i expect that on page load a call must be made to servlet which return json data which is displayed using js tree but i failing at the first step that is calling the servlet. The ajax fails to call the servlet.i tried debugging

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to use:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
              initTrees();
             });
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.